# Benchmarks not getting skipped with Err(BenchmarkError::Skip)

Tags: pallet, xcm, benchmarking, xcmv3

I am using the `pallet_xcm_benchmarks`, in the config for `pallet_xcm_benchmarks::generic`,
I have used

```rs
impl pallet_xcm_benchmarks::generic::Config for Runtime {
    fn worst_case_asset_exchange() -> Result<(MultiAssets, MultiAssets), BenchmarkError> {
        Err(BenchmarkError::Skip)
    }
}
```

**this should have skipped the benchmark**

```rs
exchange_asset {
    let (give, want) = T::worst_case_asset_exchange().map_err(|_| BenchmarkError::Skip)?;
    let assets = give.clone();

    let mut executor = new_executor::<T>(Default::default());
    executor.set_holding(give.into());
    let instruction = Instruction::ExchangeAsset {
        give: assets.into(),
        want: want.clone(),
        maximal: true,
    };
    let xcm = Xcm(vec![instruction]);
    }: {
        executor.bench_process(xcm)?;
    } verify {
        assert_eq!(executor.holding(), &want.into());
    }
```

**when I run the benchmark, it shows**

```rs
023-05-16 09:32:01 WARNING: benchmark error skipped - exchange_asset   Error: Input("Benchmark pallet_xcm_benchmarks::generic::exchange_asset failed: Benchmark not found for this pallet.")
```

The same config is used in [kusama](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/6ad852c129eef68baffd92a47797177e59d8f958/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L2085)  How to fix this problem?

Comment: What is the problem? The warning is always there. Does the CLI error out or what is the full output and exit code?